# how to temporarily pause drawing updates of a realtime data chart

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I would like a “Pause” the chart's series updates to do some job (like i have a button when i click it will suspend the chart update and then when I click resume button, it will update all suspended point in series.

I know about

```
chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates();
```

but it does not seem to work with me. I use mschart sample -- realtime data (thread safe).

Here is the full code

```
public partial class RealTimeSample : Form
{
    public RealTimeSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Thread addDataRunner;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public delegate void AddDataDelegate();
    public AddDataDelegate addDataDel;
    private void RealTimeSample_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        // create the Adding Data Thread but do not start until start button clicked
        ThreadStart addDataThreadStart = new ThreadStart(AddDataThreadLoop);
        addDataRunner = new Thread(addDataThreadStart);

        // create a delegate for adding data
        addDataDel += new AddDataDelegate(AddData);

    }



    /// Main loop for the thread that adds data to the chart.
    /// The main purpose of this function is to Invoke AddData
    /// function every 1000ms (1 second).
    private void AddDataThreadLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            chart1.Invoke(addDataDel);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void AddData()
    {
        DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (Series ptSeries in chart1.Series)
        {
            AddNewPoint(timeStamp, ptSeries);
        }
    }

    /// The AddNewPoint function is called for each series in the chart when
    /// new points need to be added.  The new point will be placed at specified
    /// X axis (Date/Time) position with a Y value in a range +/- 1 from the previous
    /// data point's Y value, and not smaller than zero.
    public void AddNewPoint(DateTime timeStamp, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series ptSeries)
    {
        double newVal = 0;

        if (ptSeries.Points.Count > 0)
        {
            newVal = ptSeries.Points[ptSeries.Points.Count - 1].YValues[0] + ((rand.NextDouble() * 2) - 1);
        }

        if (newVal < 0)
            newVal = 0;

        // Add new data point to its series.
        chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates();
        ptSeries.Points.AddXY(timeStamp.ToOADate(), rand.Next(10, 20));
        chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates();
        // remove all points from the source series older than 1.5 minutes.
        double removeBefore = timeStamp.AddSeconds((double)(90) * (-1)).ToOADate();
        //remove oldest values to maintain a constant number of data points
        while (ptSeries.Points[0].XValue < removeBefore)
        {
            ptSeries.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddMinutes(2).ToOADate();


    }

    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if ((addDataRunner.ThreadState & ThreadState.Suspended) == ThreadState.Suspended)
        {
            addDataRunner.Resume();
        }
        addDataRunner.Abort();

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void startTrending_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable all controls on the form
        startTrending.Enabled = false;
        // and only Enable the Stop button
        stopTrending.Enabled = true;

        // Predefine the viewing area of the chart
        var minValue = DateTime.Now;
        var maxValue = minValue.AddSeconds(120);

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = minValue.ToOADate();
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxValue.ToOADate();

        // Reset number of series in the chart.
        chart1.Series.Clear();

        // create a line chart series
        Series newSeries = new Series("Series1");
        newSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        newSeries.BorderWidth = 2;
        newSeries.Color = Color.OrangeRed;
        newSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart1.Series.Add(newSeries);

        // start worker threads.
        if (addDataRunner.IsAlive == true)
        {
            addDataRunner.Resume();
        }
        else
        {
            addDataRunner.Start();
        }
    }


    private void stopTrending_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (addDataRunner.IsAlive == true)
        {
            addDataRunner.Suspend();
        }

        // Enable all controls on the form
        startTrending.Enabled = true;
        // and only Disable the Stop button
        stopTrending.Enabled = false;
    }        
}
```

**EDIT:**

I figured out that as long as you set the minmum or the maximum property for the Axis the chart will keep display even if you have used

```
chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates();
```

I had to to remove those lines after i call `SuspendUpdates()` and now i can see the chart series suspended

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = ptSeries.Points[0].XValue;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.FromOADate(ptSeries.Points[0].XValue).AddMinutes(2).ToOADate();
```

Comment: While in pause mode simply add the DataPoints to a List<DataPoint> instead of the series.Points. When resuming add the list and clear it..

Comment: thanks for your comment , i used your hint and worked for me, if you put this hint as an answer i will accept it, but do you have any idea why suspendupdates not working ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**MsChart**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.7.2) does support this directly and indeed using `Series.SuspendUpdates()` is a good way but you need to do it right. (See however the update below for a drawback)

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartelementcollection-1.suspendupdates?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_ChartElementCollection_1_SuspendUpdates) says this:

> A call to the **Invalidate** method will have no effect after the
>   SuspendUpdates method is called.
>
> If you call the SuspendUpdates method several times, you will need to
>   call the ResumeUpdates method an **equal** number of times.

This would explain why it doesn't work for you: Keeping the calls **balanced** is crucial. You need to keep track of them yourself as there is no counter you could query. But if you overshoot the `ResumeUpdates` calls, nothing bad happens, extra calls are simply ignored and the next `SuspendUpdates` will pause again.

Here is an example screenshot, watch the suspension counter..!

[image]

Note that normally adding points will automatically triggger an `Invalidate`. If you are doing other things, like drawing in a `Paint` event etc.. you may need to call `Chart.Invalidate()`, which `SuspendUpdates` will prevent, until cancelled by the same number of `ResumeUpdates`..

---

Alternatively you can also use one of these simple workarounds:

- The most straightforward will create the `DataPoints` via a constructor and then either

  - use `series.Add(theNewPoint)` for **normal**, or..
  - use `someList<DataPoint>.Add(theNewPoint)` for **paused** mode.

When setting to pause mode simply add all points to the `series.Points` before clearing it. Unfortunately there is no `points.AddRange` so you will have to use a `foreach` loop. Maybe `chart.SuspendLayout` could help with performance.

- The other workaround that comes to mind may or may not be suitable: You could play with the `xAxis.Maximum` and maybe `xAxis.Minimum values`. By setting them to fixed values you would allow addding points to the right without displaying them. To show the whole set of points you would reset them to `double.NaN`. This may work for you but it may also interfer with what you have.

**Update:** As noted by OP, the data are updated when he changes the `Minimum` and/or `Maximum` of an `Axis`. The same effect will show on many other occasions:

- Calling `chart.AreasRecalculateAxesScale();`
- Changing the chart's `Size`
- Changing **any** Axis property like `Color` or `Width`..
- Changing the `LegendText` of a `Series`
- and many more..

So I guess the updated data are needed whenever the `ChartArea` is manipulated and forced to update itself..

So, this may well make the 1st workaround the better because the **more robust** solution.

Comment: It does not suspend my drawing,... my problem was that chart  do not suspend updates to series ... even when i call it to suspend,   the alternative work around (DataPoint list) works with me but i think chart.series.suspend will be better performance, so if you could please put the source could for the image you made , will be very helpful.

Comment: It does not suspend my drawing,... my problem was that chart  do not suspend updates to series ... even when i call it to suspend,   the alternative work around (DataPoint list) works with me but i think chart.series.suspend will be better performance, so if you could please put the source could for the image you made , will he very helpful.

Comment: If you try the code in my original question ... chart is keep going addpoints even when i call chart1.Series.SuspendUpdates(); twice ...without calling resumeupdates

Comment: I can but there is really __nothing__ to it: A Timer adds points a button calls suspend and increments the numericUpdown, the other button calls Resume and decrements. That is all there is to it! 5 lines of code..

Comment: Well of course it keeps adding points as long as the code runs, or in my case the timer. They just don't show. You can observe the jumps when the update is resumed.. Do you mean the display gets updated all the time? Btw: I'm not sure about the perfromance; adding a point to a List is as cheap as it gets. And adding each to the chart is what happens anyway..

Comment: Looking at the code I wonder why you are suspending to increbily often? And where that is connected to a pause button or function??

Comment: Yes i mean the display keeps updated all the time ... points drawn .. no difference if i call suspend .....

Comment: For my code now there is no button to suspend ... but i believe  that the output for the code .... should display nothing however .. i see points displayed normally

Comment: Well that is strange but I can't reproduce for lack of time. Maybe you want to play with a simpler setup, maybe with a timer to convince yourself that and how it works. Also: If not for a user interaction, why do you want to pause in the first place???

Comment: It was for user , i edited the code before i post here , this code was my last hope to force it to not display anything to see if the suspend works in the first place or not ,... anyway thanks for all the efforts, i will try with simpler example again

Comment: i figured out why it was not working, check my edit if you have time ,... thanks again for help

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for keeping me updated! - I have updated the answer to reflect this and some more and similar observations